# How to install .jar on Zend Server CE with Java Bridge On Linux

Tags: php, zend-framework

My windows setup works perfectly, I am now moving it to amazon aws using amazon linux.

I seem to have everything installed correctly except that java bridge cannot find my .jar file.  I keep getting class not found errors.

On windows there was a java_bridge_server.ini where I set the classpath, I can't find this on the linux install.

EDIT:  Before asking this I had tried to update bashrc with CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:[path to .jar] and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

CLASSPATH is not actually used.  Update /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-jb.ini 
zend_wd.env.java_daemon=CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/zend/bin/javamw.jar:[path to your jar here]

Why couldn't I find this anywhere on the web!?

Hopes this helps the next developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place your .jar file here: `/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib` and then `service tomcat6 restart`